# Get all hostnames on network

Tags: objective-c, networking

How can I get all hostnames of all machines on the same network? Is there any Obj-C library for such tasks? I am using GCDAsyncSocket lib to communicate via UDP and now I want to list all available hosts (or at least IP addresses) in the app instead of having to type the IP address manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't.   TCP/IP networks don't work that way.

If you want automatic discovery of services, you should be using [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/).

Comment: does Bonjour can be used to fetch all available devices connected to my local network irrespective of services? Link Fing app